# Shelah’s Representation Theorem: existence of scales

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic, pcf-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a singular cardinal of countable cofinality. Shelah’s Representation Theorem states that there is an increasing sequence of regular cardinals $\langle\delta_n\rangle_{n<\omega}$, cofinal in $\lambda$, for which there is a scale $\langle f_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha<\lambda^+}$. A scale here is a sequence of functions from $\prod_{n<\omega}\delta_n$ which is increasing and cofinal with respect to $<^\ast$. For functions $f$ and $g$ in $\prod_{n<\omega}\delta_n$, $f <^\ast g$
means that there exists $n<\omega$ such that for every $m>n$, $f(m) < g(m)$.

I wonder whether one can get a slightly stronger form of the Theorem. More precisely, suppose $\lambda>\aleph_\omega$ is a singular cardinal of countable cofinality. Can one always find an increasing sequence of successor cardinals $\langle\delta_n\rangle_{n<\omega}$, cofinal in $\lambda$, and a scale $\langle f_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha<\lambda^+}$ relative to the sequence $\langle\delta_n\rangle_{n<\omega}$?

Comment: I conjectured it is consistent for for some singular cardinal lambda of countable cofinality to have lambda^+ as TCF only via countable sequences of weakly compact cardinals (up to a finite set). Ben-Neria recently told me he has a candidate for such a model. I'll say more about it in the "Perspectives on Set Theory" conference next month.

Comment: Chiming in:  a positive answer to your question is enough to show that successors of singular cardinals cannot be Jonsson, which would resolve a major open question in the area.